# Select unique elements in pandas rows made of sequence of strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains several columns. One of them groups some keywords together:

```
Column1                 Column2
key1, key2                    3
key1, key3, key7             1.2
key2                         2.2
...                          ...
```

I would like to have a list with all keys in the dataframe (so key1, key2, key3, key7 in the example above). Each row element is a string, so that 'key1, key2' is a string, but so far I have only managed to get the unique strings, not the unique keys one by one. I guess I have to split the strings somehow and analyze the keys one by one, but how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) and [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
uniq = df['Column1'].str.split(', ').explode().unique()
```

Or with [`Series.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html):

```
uniq = df['Column1'].str.split(', ').explode().drop_duplicates()
```

Or set comprehension with `split`:

```
uniq = set(y for x in df['Column1'] for y in x.split(', '))
```

---

If need analyze all data:

```
df1 = df.assign(Column1 = df['Column1'].str.split(', ')).explode('Column1')
```